# Validate OpenShift objects defined in yaml before actually applying or executing it

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I have a OpenShift template in template.yaml file which includes following objects - deployment-config, pod, service and route. I am using the following command to execute the yaml:

```
oc process -f template.yml | oc apply -f -
```

I want to perform following validations before I actually apply/execute the yaml:

1. YAML syntax validation - if there are any issues with the YAML syntax.
2. OpenShift schema validation - to check if the object definition abides by the OpenShift object schema.

It seems that the command 'oc process' is doing following checking:

1. Basic YAML syntax validation
2. Template object schema validation

How to perform schema validation of other objects (e.g. deployment-config, service, pod, etc.) that are defined in template.yaml?

Comment: At this point in time there's no such option available in openshift, other than actually submitting the template to a test project. I've created https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/11152 as an RFE.

Answer (score 10):

This is now possible with the OpenShift client (and on Kubernetes in general), e.g.

```
$ oc login
Username: john.doe
Password: 
Login successful.

$ oc apply -f openshift/template-app.yaml --dry-run
template "foobar-app" created (dry run)
```

It's also possible to process the template locally, thus you can avoid sending it to the server first, e.g.

```
$ oc process -f openshift/template-app.yaml --local -p APP_NAME=foo | oc apply --dry-run --validate -f -
deploymentconfig "foo" created (dry run)
service "foo" created (dry run)
```

Also note the `--validate` option I'm using for schema validation. Unfortunately, you still have to log in for the `apply` command to work (there's no `--local` option for `apply`).

Oddly, this feature is not described in the [CLI documentation](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html), however it's mentioned on the help screen:

```
$ oc apply --help
Apply a configuration to a resource by filename or stdin.

JSON and YAML formats are accepted.

Usage:
  oc apply -f FILENAME [options]

...

Options:
      ...
      --dry-run=false: If true, only print the object that would be sent, without sending it.
      ...
      --validate=false: If true, use a schema to validate the input before sending it

Use "oc <command> --help" for more information about a given command.
Use "oc options" for a list of global command-line options (applies to all commands).
```

Comment: In the meantime, some more Kubernetes YAML validation tools have surfaced (e.g. we're using `kubeval` for quite some time now). A [recent article on learnk8s.io](https://learnk8s.io/validating-kubernetes-yaml) compares 6 of those validation tools: `kubeval`, `kube-score`, `config-lint`, `copper`, `conftest`, `polaris`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue with cryptic errors coming back from the `oc process` command.

However if you go into the Openshift Console and use the "Add to Project" link at the top of the console, choose the "Import YAML / JSON" option and import your YAML/JSON that way you get ***slightly*** more useful errors.