# How can I create the operator which will check yaml before using it in openshift?

Tags: operators, openshift, openshift-origin

The operator should try to find some string in YAML file, which the developer try to add in openshift. If there is this string in YAML (For example: "My name is Kirill") the operator must prohibit to add this YAML (if it's possible with some message to developer) otherwise add this YAML

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It would help people answer your question if you provide some background to what you have tried already.

Comment: I have tried nothing, but I guess my task has some common with it. Instead of checking basic YAML validation I need to find some string and if there is this string, it equals to wrong YAML validation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824409/validate-openshift-objects-defined-in-yaml-before-actually-applying-or-executing